How to avoid wasting reader investment with a thematically disappointing ending?
I'm drafting a story around chasing dreams and facing the possibility of said dreams being a lie in the end. For this, I have a main character doggedly chasing a goal that's extremely hard to achieve but ultimately doable with enough sacrifices at first glance.
He faces other characters chasing different dreams with similar determination. He's supposed to see them all achieving their dreams and experiencing an unsatisfying conclusion. Each character is supposed to represent a "wrong" reaction to encountering this.
To thematically complete the story, I intend for the main character to face the same fate at the end but express the "proper" reaction. My problem is the readers' investment of the protagonist's pursuit and the progress he makes throughout the story. I'm afraid of wasting their emotional investment with my deliberately unsatisfying conclusion. How would I thread this needle?

Not an answer because you already got more than one. Just that it sounds intruiging. Go for it. We're chock-full of rose-colored happy endings, it doesn't hurt at all for some literature to resemble real human life.

Discovering what is real and what is a lie... this must be presented as a more valuable attainment than the prospect of achieving a dream that is a lie.

Even if the novel ends without the character's initial goal being achieved, that does not mean it can't still end with catharsis.
The character might look at their goal with a new perspective, and realise that they no longer really want/need to achieve it.
They might decide that what is important is the ongoing pursuit — that it's undertaking the journey that mattered, not actually reaching the goal.
They might look back over their actions to reach this point, and realise that they have achieved something equally important.  (The classic “what you wanted is not always what you needed” Aesop)
…
Or, for a more tragic ending, they might look back and see all of the opportunities that they squandered and sacrificed in pursuit of this goal.  The old “so, you've won — but at what cost?” story, but with the added twist that they didn't win.
The important thing is that the arc completes, or the cycle closes: from the sounds of things, you don't want your reader to go away feeling happy, you want them to go away feeling pensive or thoughtful.  The sort of story that sticks with them, and has them thinking about their own goals/dreams, and comes to mind at strange times long after they finish reading.
Essentially, you want to ensure that the reader gets something out of the ending, even if it is not necessarily what they were hoping/expecting to get out of it…
… which, really, sounds exactly what your story is about in the first place! ☺

That sounds like a really cool idea. I agree with Ben, it might not become a best-seller and whilst I wouldn't use the word disappoint, a lot of readers may feel it wasn't the ending they wanted.
However this doesn't mean that a) you shouldn't do it or b) it's a bad idea.
SPOILER FOR 1984
I read 1984 and initially finished it incredibly disappointed. The book essentially finished exactly how it started. The dictatorship won, life continued, there was no heroic victory. I thought that was ridiculous and a complete waste of my time to read. Then I thought about it a bit more and realised . . . holy moly, what an icon. Our generation is often keen on a clear ending. Everything resolves. Whether the resolution is happy, bitter-sweet or something like that, we tend to only like resolved endings. I think that needs to be changed.
The kind of ending you have in mind is a fairly controversial one. But that, in my opinion, is a bold, brave and brilliant move. Instead of a resolved ending it sparks thought within the reader about reality. Once I got over the intial outrage at 1984, it very quickly became one of my most respected books. It's the same kind of vibe when an author kills off a fully developed character in the middle of the book - damn does it hurt but it's not some cheap death at the beginning or a tragic ending. It's brave . . . and probably hated by most readers whilst also increasing their respect for the author.
Which brings me onto another point. Write what you want to read not what readers want you to write. Whilst you should think about target audience and what would sell well and all that stuff, you're the one writing it. If you're not happy with what you're writing then how are you gonna be inspired to keep going? Also, what if your story was that big kablooie that made everyone realise how much they loved thought-provoking endings!?
In short: Go for it. It sounds brilliant, don't doubt yourself.

The purpose of 1984 isn't to tell a heroic story, but to offer social commentary. It sounds like the OP is similarly focused on an idea rather than a narrative.

This sounds like an interesting and brave approach!
You seem to have clear ideas about ‘right’ and ‘wrong’ reactions to finding that a goal is a let-down.
So I'd suggest making a lot of that.  Perhaps having some discussion about how to react in that situation, what makes a reaction ‘right’, why it's so desirable, and so on — early on (foreshadowing), and/or involving other characters after they hit their own let-downs.  Perhaps by showing bad consequences from other characters' ‘wrong’ reactions.  Perhaps having the main character reflect and come to similar conclusions, if that comes naturally to them.  (But be careful; you probably don't want it to look too obviously like an author insert or sponsor's message.)
However you do it, you need the reader to recognise that the main character is responding the right way.  It needs to be very obvious, not just that their reaction contrasts strongly with that of the other characters, but that it's somehow correct or beneficial or honourable.
That may take some work and skill to set up properly.  But if you do it right, then the reader can find that reaction cathartic and satisfying (even if the main character doesn't).

If you want to write bestselling popular fiction, write something else. You have become infatuated with a clever idea that sounds fascinating when you discuss it with your friends over beer but that leaves readers disappointed.
If you love the idea too much to let it go, this is what I do: While I write one novel, I'm working on plotting multiple other stories at the same time. Some of them are years old and still unsatisfactory. The may never get written. But some are slowly progressing. The advantage with this approach is that I never get stuck on one story. When I don't know how to solve a problem like yours, I just let that story rest and turn to another one. And sometimes, weeks or months or year later, I have an insight that solves the problem with that story. Some of those solutions come from the distance I gain with this approach. I'm never so invested with a certain idea that I cannot let it go. Thus, many of my stories have undergone fundamental changes that would have been impossible for me if I had tried to force them like you do.

Every tragedy involves a character failing to achieve their goal, and if that character survives, somehow dealing with that failure.
Poorly written tragedies are indeed consigned to the dustbin. But that is true of every category of fiction. Exceptional tragedies become classics and resonate throughout history.

However, on the other hand, this might be the difference between a run-of-the-mill, dime-a-dozen bestseller and a literary work. While there's need for the first, there definitely is a clear need for the second as well. I can't see anywhere in the OP that his main interest is his bank account, so you shouldn't try to discourage him in the pursuit of the second goal.
